# SPCascade Dropdown Required Field

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spservices

We are running SharePoint Online, and are using jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js with jquery-1.10.2.js.

Simply we tried using SPCascadeDropdowns documented at the link below: 
`https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation`

We faced an issue when I tried to make the field as required, and we can't solve this issue.

If we make Country and Region as required fields on the state list and if we apply Cascading Dropdowns, the Region drop down will depend on the Country selected, it doesn't work.

Comment: what doesn't work? the script altogether? You can submit a form without the field populated? Code and/or screenshots will help, this is all rather vague.

Comment: we can't show the regions that is only on the country selected ( region and country are two lookup fields ) , for this field unrequired the filter works fine with SPCascadeDropdowns , but when we make this two fields as required the filter doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain we do this without a problem.

What version of SharePoint?

This sounds vaguely familiar - If I recall correctly (and I may not be) there was an issue with SPServices where MS changed the way they formed the HTML of the form for required fields which broke SPServices. But I thought it has been worked around in SPServices. Search the issue database for SPServices on Codeplex or the release notes and i think it explains it.

Comment: we are using sharepoint online ( office 365 ) , with sorrow we can't apply Cascading Dropdowns with required fields ,, Mannaggia can you help me please ?

Comment: you must to know that , this issue only for the custom forms created by SP designer , but there is no problem with the default forms newform.aspx , editform.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I got a request from a (big) customer for a cascaded field on his SharePoint 2013. The name of the required field changes in the form: you need to put in the script :
`parentColumn: "DUM Required",`
in french :
`parentColumn: "DUM Champ obligatoire",`